# Poner texto por defecto en formulario flutter

Tags: android, formularios, flutter, dart

Tengo un formulario en dart tal que asi:

```
FormBuilderTextField(
    attribute: "NombreTitular1",
    autofocus: true,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    helperText: cliente.getNombre1(),
        labelText: "Nombre del titular",
    ),
    controller: ControllerNombre1,
    maxLength: 30,
    validators: [
        FormBuilderValidators.required(errorText: "Este campo es obligatorio],
),
```

Quiero que en el Form me aparezca por defecto un texto con un nombre, pero no se como hacerlo. Lo que quiero es un formulario para que el usuario edite sus datos, pero claro tiene que ver sus antiguos datos para editarlos si no no tiene sentido el formulario. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Quieres que por defecto recupere el dato que tiene previamente?

Comment: No quiero por defecto darle yo un dato, el usuario va a modificar sus datos que tengo en una base de datos, yo quiero coger esos datos de la BD y mostrarselos en el formulario, para que el los pueda modificar

Answer (score 1):

Para asignar un valor inicial al [`FormBuilderTextField`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/flutter_form_builder/latest/flutter_form_builder/FormBuilderTextField-class.html) debes utilizar la propiedad `initialValue`

#### Ejemplo:

```
FormBuilderTextField(
  attribute: "NombreTitular1",
  initialValue: "Hola mundo!",
  autofocus: true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    helperText: cliente.getNombre1(),
    labelText: "Nombre del titular",
  ),
  controller: ControllerNombre1,
  maxLength: 30,
  validators: [
    FormBuilderValidators.required(errorText: "Este campo es obligatorio"),
  ],
),
```

Comment: el helper text me muestra el dato en una zona inferior del formulario no en el formulario en si, si no me equivoco

Comment: Pero creo que esta respuesta está bien. No te funciona con el initialValue que indica?